# Spring Security Password encoding concat

Tags: spring, encoding, spring-security

I am looking for how Spring password encoding works. How does it concats string?
For example, I have password 'password' and salt 'salt'. How does it call encode method?

- encode('passwordsalt')
- encode('saltpassword')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security concatenates password and salt like this:

```
 password{salt}
```

The concatenated string is put in the hashing function, for example with MD5:

```sql
 md5('password{salt}')
```

Security note: A single MD5 is considered quite weak nowadays. Just an example.